# How to calculate average of a measure using Dax in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

In power bi, I created a measure to calculate the daily average of each department head. I got an error. First I used this formula. I got an error message like

> 'column is not found in query1'

.

```
AvgBydepartmentHead = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM(TableName[Total]),
    SUM(TableName[Days worked])
```

Then I used the other formula

```
AvgBydepartmentHead = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM([Total]),
    SUM([Days worked])
```

Got error like

> The sum function only accepts column reference as the argument 1

Both Total and days worked are measures.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kv5b.png

How to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: A screenshot of the problem will help everyone in answering this. Additionally, if you could provide a sample data, it would make things easier.

Comment: Thank you. I have added an link to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "calculated fields", but if they are **Measures** you don't need an additional aggregation, the following should work:

```
AvgBydepartmentHead = DIVIDE( [Total], [Days worked] )
```

It's also unclear what the message 'table is not found in query1' has to do with your problem.

Comment: Thank you Peter for the response. I did some edit to the question and also included a link to see the data.